# VS2010 ASP.NET Configuration

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config, httpmodule

When I try to open ASP.NET Configuration, I get the follow error

[image]

I've tried all the available solutions from google, but none of them worked and some of them were posted before 2010, anyone have a solution for vs2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it, here is what i did:

1. Find a computer that has ASP.NET configuration working(i was lucky enough that asp.net configuration on my pc is working, if you don't have one, you can message me, i am happy to provide one if your framework version is 4.0.3031).
2. Copy all the files under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework(your version)\asp.netwebadminfiles into a usb.
3. Go to the pc with the problem and go to the same folder, cut and paste the files inside that folder in a new folder(for backup purpose, in case something goes wrong).
4. Copy/Cut and paste the working files in your usb to that folder and all is done.
5. If the target framework error is showing, just change the target framework in web.config to the correct framework.

Hope this helps, i was frustrated for days that there isn't a solution and this just popped up in my mind, very happy :)